# The Meaning of ~는대

Tags: grammar

I thought ~는대 means 'but/however' but there is an example shows that ~는대 means 'I heard that.../It is said that....'

For example:

> 한국 상품을 잘 팔린대
>
> *I heard that Korean products sell well.*

So, which one is correct?

Comment: I don't think 한국 상품을 잘 팔린대 quite makes sense because 을 denotes an object, but 팔리다 is already a passive form... you could say '한국 상품을 잘 판대' or '한국 상품이/은 잘 팔린대'

Comment: To add, I think "한국 상품이 잘 팔린대" is better. "한국 상품을 잘 판대" sounds like "(I heard) they're good at selling Korean products."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an error: -는**데** means 'but/however' among other things, while -ㄴ/는**대** is short for -ㄴ/는다고 해, meaning "it is said that.." as you said. The other commenter is correct, only use 을/를 if the verb takes a direct object.

In any case it's not as though you couldn't have one grammar/word meaning two things, it's a language with lots of homophones.

Comment: Oh, I see!! Thank you! I have another question related to the usage of ~ㄴ/는대. Let's say I want to say something that will happen in the future, for example, "They said the weather will be good tomorrow", is the sentence "내일 날씨가 좋을대요" correct? It is confusing whether to use 좋대요 or 좋을대요 to indicate that it will happen in the future.

Comment: Because 좋다 is an adjective, you should use -대, not -ㄴ/는대: "내일 날씨가 좋대요" is correct. For past tense, you can say "어제 날씨가 좋았대요." (Korean usually uses present tense to talk about scheduled events, plans, weather forecasts, and such, even if they're in the future.)

Comment: For verbs, you can use -ㄴ/는대 like: "내일 우리 집에 온대요." or "일곱 시에 문 닫는대요." Although you could also say "오겠대요"/"닫겠대요", it slightly changes meaning: "온대요" sounds more natural if it is already planned/decided, while "오겠대요" emphasizes the decision itself.

Comment: You can use 겠다고 해요 (겠대요) or 을 거라고 해요 (을 거래요) for future tense, so 내일 날씨가 좋겠대요 or 내일 날씨가 좋을 거래요. But as pointed out above, present tense can be used to describe future occurrences, it just depends on context.